# Pegar string por formato

Tags: php, array, string

Tenho um array com 1000 índices com textos e números aleatórios amontados,  preciso pegar nesse texto trechos que estejam em formatos particulares que contenham quantidades de caracteres pre definidas, como uma cadeia de caracteres da seguinte forma: 65 45 98 12 15 98 (17 caracteres) ou 04668475 03/1980 (formato de data após sequencia numérica), como posso criar uma função de filtro para passar os índices por ele e só me retornar na tela as strings que se adequem a esses formatos ?

Exemplo informal:

```php
$strings = array("1" => "12 32 87 98 54", "2" => "154654651", "3" => "1354654654  45 45 45 45 45");
$mascara = ## ## ## ## ##;
$contar = count($strings);

for($i=0; $i < $contar; $i++){

    if($mascara == $strings[$i]){
        echo $strings[$i]."encontrado";
    }else{
        echo $strings[$i]."nao encontrado";
    }

}
```

No caso os índices seriam comparados a mascara e caso exista um trecho da string com o formato da mascara seria printado como encontrado.

Comment: Expressão regular, mas para responder melhor iremos precisar que você detalhe melhor qual é a regra de filtro, isto é, qual será exatamente o formato desejado, quais valores deverão retornar e quais não.

Comment: O problema é que os valores são randomizados porém ordenados em formatos, preciso pegar conforme os formatos e não os valores :/

Comment: Por isso a expressão regular. Edite a pergunta e explique essa frase: "preciso pegar strings que estejam em **formatos particulares** que contenham certa quantidade de números em **certos formatos**"

Comment: por exemplo, tenho a seguinte string $texto = ":63544 42168798975 12/1990"; preciso de uma função de filtro que ignore os valores randômicos :63544 e pegue os trechos constantes que tenham 11 caracteres e a data deles seguida.

Comment: Então, é exatamente isso que preciso que você explique **na pergunta**. Todas as linhas seguem esse formato, de um número aleatório, uma sequência de 11 dígitos e uma data? Se não, quais são todos os formatos que deseja considerar?

Comment: tem dois formatos "0000 0000 0000 0000 00/0000 000" e esse "0000000000000000 00/0000 000" os textos que preciso pegar estão constantemente nesse formato.

Answer (score 0):

Como [comentado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268661/pegar-string-por-formato?noredirect=1#comment550954_268661), você terá apenas dois formatos permitidos: "0000 0000 0000 0000 00/0000 000" e "0000000000000000 00/0000 000", ou seja, uma sequência de 16 dígitos, podendo ser agrupados a cada quatro, seguido de uma data e uma sequência de três dígitos.

Assim, podemos definir uma expressão regular:

```
((\d{4}\s?){3}\d{4}) (\d{2}\/\d{4}) (\d{3})
```

Onde:

- `((\d{4}\s?){3}\d{4})` irá capturar a sequência de 16 dígitos, podendo existir, ou não, os espaços a cada quatro dígitos. Leia-se: quatro dígitos, `\d{4}`, seguido de um espaço em branco opcional, `\s?`, repetidos três vezes, `{3}`, seguido de quatro dígitos, `\d{4}`, entre parenteses, para capturar o valor;
- Um espaço em branco;
- `(\d{2}\/\d{4})` irá capturar a data: dois dígitos seguidos de quatro dígitos;
- Outro espaço;
- `(\d{3})` irá capturar qualquer número de três dígitos;

Se você quer validar um texto permitindo verificando se ele segue rigidamente este formato, você pode iniciar a expressão com `^` e terminar com `$`, que definem o início e o fim do texto, assim, se o texto possuir, ou não, qualquer coisa que fuja do formato o filtro irá bloquear.

```
^((\d{4}\s?){3}\d{4}) (\d{2}\/\d{4}) (\d{3})$
```

Veja um exemplo simples:

```
$tests = [
  "0000 0000 0000 0000 00/0000 000",   // válido
  "0000000000000000 00/0000 000",      // válido
  "00000000 00000000 00/0000 000",     // válido
  "0000000 000000000 00/0000 000",     // inválido: espaços errados
  "0000 000 0000 0000 00/0000 000",    // inválido: tamanho da sequência errada
  "000000000000000 00/0000 000",       // inválido: tamanho da sequência errada
];

foreach($tests as $test)
{
  if (preg_match("/^((\d{4}\s?){3}\d{4}) (\d{2}\/\d{4}) (\d{3})$/", $test, $matches))
  {
    print_r($matches);
  }
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/23RRBP) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/NiftySandyPapillon)</sup>